# Building against iOS4.2 with deployment target set to 3.2 causes orientation problems

Tags: ipad, ios, orientation

Basically the question says it all.  I am building an iPad app against version 4.2 of the SDK, and my client is testing the app on a device with 3.2.2 installed, and they are having terrible orientation problems (views totally messing up when the device orientation is changed).

The strange thing is that the app has been built against 3.2 previously, worked fine, and has had no changes made to the parts of the UIView Delegate that support orientation changes.  My only thought is that something has changed in iOS4.2 that is causing the problem.

I'm well aware that supporting OS's a whole version ago isn't really best practice, and I would happily continue building the app against 3.2 as I'm not using any features that have surfaced in 4.0+ (even multi-tasking due to the nature of the app), but thanks to Apple getting rid of older versions of the SDK each time you upgrade Xcode I can't do this :\

Any suggestions of either a way of testing compatibility with older versions of the OS, or recommendations on a minimum OS to support (my thought is 4.0).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet they messed with the API when they swapped out the orientation lock stuff. iPad users are some of the most dedicated apple users in the marketplace. There are going to be very few running older versions. I'd just bite the bullet and support 4.0 and up.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice Aurum :)  It's just a shame there is such a gap between 3.2.2 and 4.2!  I'm surprised there aren't more developers having issues with rebuilding pad apps against the newer SDK.

Comment: Most devs don't test on old stuff. I know that I got bitten by a memory leak and some NSString operation errors that only happened on old hardware. You can either not support it, or try your best to do so. There is a threshold where you just have to dump it and change your minimum OS requirement.

Comment: In the end I only supported 4.0+ as it was going to be impossible to debug on an older OS :)